# JRuby with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have been working with Ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0.6, and i am new to JRuby. I want to know whether Apache Tomcat ( web server ) can serve multiple requests of single Jruby WAR file ? Any website that can confirm the issue? I googled for the same but couldn't find concrete answer.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes. Look at config.threadsafe! https://gist.github.com/samkiller/1564440

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, we have been doing so for about a year under Tomcat 5.